# NHibernate Validator and Null DateTime

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

There must be a simple solution out there, I'm trying to use NHibernate Validator attributes on my DateTime properties. If the value is null (via `[NotNull]`), I want it to fail validation. When I submit a null value it gets converted to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and NHibernate doesn't pick that up as null. I guess I could write a custom validation rule that returns false if that date is submitted, but surely there's a standard way around this?

Clarification: This is an example class,

```
public class ExampleClass {

  [NotNull]
  public virtual DateTime MySpecialDateProperty { get; set; }

  [NotNullOrEmpty]
  public virtual string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

I have NHibernate Validator setup so that in my controller, I can do:

`newExampleClass.IsValid()` and if it is true it'll persist in the database, if not I'll return `newExampleClass.ValidationResults()`

When I create a new instance of `ExampleClass`, the `MySpecialDateProperty` initializes as 1/1/0001 ... and the validator doesn't pick that up as a null value.

Edit 2: Should I set `DateTime` to nullable (`DateTime?`) which would prevent NHibernate from setting the value to the minimum DateTime?

Comment: what does "submit" mean in this context? Is your *property* nullable?

Comment: Does my clarification clear it up, sorry I guess not everyone can read my mind ;)

Comment: This is not NHibernate setting the value to the minimum DateTime. It is the .NET Framework. DateTime is a value type (Struct), not a reference type (Class). 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx You cannot set a DateTime to null in the same way that you cannot say int foo = null, or bool inValid = null;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a nullable type. DateTime is initialized to DateTime.MinValue (1/1/0001). Try:

```
  [NotNull]
  public virtual DateTime? MySpecialDateProperty { get; set; }
```